Symfony PHPUnit Test Error: Cannot Instantiate Interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface
I am working on writing PHPUnit tests for my Symfony application but keep encountering an error that I am unable to resolve. The error message is:
1) App\Tests\PaymentControllerTest::testProcessPaymentSuccess
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface


This error occurs when running my PHPUnit test, and it seems to be related to the instantiation of the EntityManagerInterface. I have set up my test to mock various dependencies including the InvoiceRepository, InvoiceService, and HttpClientInterface. Despite my efforts to properly configure the service container and set these mocks, I still receive this error.
I have tried the following approaches:
Creating Mocks for Dependencies: Ensured that all dependencies, including the EntityManagerInterface, are mocked in the setup of my test.
Configuring Services for Testing: Updated my services_test.yaml configuration to make services public during tests.
Setting Mocks in the Container: Used self::getContainer()->set to add the mocks into the container for the test environment.
Despite these steps, the error persists. It appears that Symfony's Dependency Injection container is still attempting to instantiate the EntityManagerInterface directly, which is not possible since it is an interface.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on properly configuring mocks for Symfony's EntityManagerInterface in a PHPUnit test? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Controller
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Invoice;
use App\Entity\Transaction;
use App\Repository\InvoiceRepository;
use App\Service\InvoiceService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class PaymentController extends AbstractController
{
    private HttpClientInterface $client;
    private mixed $baseUrl;
    private mixed $apiKey;
    private mixed $merchantId;
    private InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository;
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private InvoiceService $invoiceService;
    private Pdf $pdf;

    public function __construct(
        HttpClientInterface $client,
        InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        Pdf $pdf
    ) {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->baseUrl = $_ENV['PAYWAY_BASE_URL'];
        $this->apiKey = $_ENV['PAYWAY_API_KEY'];
        $this->merchantId = $_ENV['PAYWAY_MERCHANT_ID'];
        $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/process-payment/{id}", name="process_payment", methods={"POST"})
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     */
    public function processPayment(Request $request, int $id): RedirectResponse|Response
    {
        $invoiceData = $this->invoiceRepository->findInvoiceData($id);

        if (!$invoiceData) {
            return $this->json(['error' => 'Invoice not found'], 404);
        }

        $paymentData = [
            'merchantId' => $this->merchantId,
            'customerNumber' => $invoiceData['accountNumber'],
            'transactionType' => 'payment',
            'principalAmount' => $invoiceData['totalAmount'],
            'currency' => 'aud',
            'customerIpAddress' => $request->getClientIp(),
            'orderNumber' => $invoiceData['invoiceNumber'],
            'customField1' => $invoiceData['mirn'],
        ];

        $response = $this->client->request('POST', $this->baseUrl . '/transactions', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($this->apiKey . ':'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => $paymentData,
        ]);

        $responseData = $response->toArray();

        // Handle response and update the invoice accordingly
        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200 && isset($responseData['status']) && $responseData['status'] === 'APPROVED') {
            // Payment approved, finalize the invoice
            return $this->finalizeInvoice($id, $request);
        } else {
            // Payment failed, handle the error
            return $this->json(['error' => 'Payment failed', 'details' => $responseData], $response->getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/finalize-invoice/{id}", name="finalize_invoice", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function finalizeInvoice(int $id, Request $request): RedirectResponse|Response
    {
        $invoice = $this->invoiceRepository->find($id);

        if (!$invoice) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Invoice not found');
        }

        $invoice->setIsDraft(false);
        $invoice->setIssuedDate(new \DateTime());

        /** @var Transaction $transaction */
        $transaction = $invoice->getTransactions()[0];
        $transaction?->setIsInvoiced(true);
        $transaction?->setBillingStatus(Transaction::BILLING_STATUS_BILLED);

        $this->entityManager->persist($invoice);
        $this->entityManager->persist($transaction);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $html = $this->renderView('invoice/pdf.html.twig', $this->invoiceService->generateInvoiceData($invoice));

        $this->pdf->setTimeout(120);
        $this->pdf->setOption('enable-local-file-access', true);

        $pdf = $this->pdf->getOutputFromHtml($html, [
            'encoding' => 'utf-8',
            'page-size' => 'A4',
            'orientation' => 'Portrait',
            'margin-top' => 5,
            'margin-bottom' => 5,
            'margin-left' => 5,
            'margin-right' => 5,
            'dpi' => 300,
        ]);

        $pdfPath = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public/uploads/invoices/' . $invoice->getId() . '/pdf/';
        $invoiceName = $invoice->getSite()->getMirn() . ' - Gas-Invoice - ' . $invoice->getInvoiceDate()->format('M-Y') . ' - Perpetual-Energy';
        $pdfFileName = $invoiceName . '.pdf';

        $filesystem = new Filesystem();
        $filesystem->mkdir($pdfPath);

        if (file_put_contents($pdfPath . $pdfFileName, $pdf) === false) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to save the PDF file.');
        }

        $invoice->setPdfFileName($pdfFileName);
        $this->entityManager->persist($invoice);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Invoice finalized successfully.');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_billing');
    }
}

Test Class :
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Controller\PaymentController;
use App\Entity\Invoice;
use App\Entity\Transaction;
use App\Repository\InvoiceRepository;
use App\Service\InvoiceService;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\MockHttpClient;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Response\MockResponse;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PaymentControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $invoiceRepositoryMock;
    private $entityManagerMock;
    private $invoiceServiceMock;
    private $pdfMock;
    private $httpClientMock;
    private $controller;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->invoiceRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(InvoiceRepository::class);
        $this->entityManagerMock = $this->createMock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $this->invoiceServiceMock = $this->createMock(InvoiceService::class);
        $this->pdfMock = $this->createMock(Pdf::class);
        $this->httpClientMock = $this->createMock(HttpClientInterface::class);

        self::getContainer()->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager', $this->entityManagerMock);
        self::getContainer()->set(InvoiceRepository::class, $this->invoiceRepositoryMock);
        self::getContainer()->set(InvoiceService::class, $this->invoiceServiceMock);
        self::getContainer()->set(Pdf::class, $this->pdfMock);
        self::getContainer()->set(HttpClientInterface::class, $this->httpClientMock);

        $this->controller = new PaymentController(
            $this->httpClientMock,
            $this->invoiceRepositoryMock,
            $this->entityManagerMock,
            $this->invoiceServiceMock,
            $this->pdfMock
        );
        $this->controller->setContainer(self::getContainer());
    }

    public function testProcessPaymentSuccess()
    {
        $response = new MockResponse(json_encode(['status' => 'APPROVED']), ['http_code' => 200]);
        $this->httpClientMock = new MockHttpClient([$response]);

        $invoiceData = [
            'id' => 1,
            'accountNumber' => '123456',
            'totalAmount' => 100.0,
            'invoiceNumber' => 'INV-12345',
            'mirn' => 'MIRN-67890'
        ];
        $this->invoiceRepositoryMock->method('findInvoiceData')->willReturn($invoiceData);

        $invoice = $this->createMock(Invoice::class);
        $transaction = $this->createMock(Transaction::class);
        $transactions = new ArrayCollection([$transaction]);
        $invoice->method('getTransactions')->willReturn($transactions);
        $this->invoiceRepositoryMock->method('find')->willReturn($invoice);

        $mockContract = new \stdClass();
        $mockContract->billingAddress = '123 Fake Street';
        $this->invoiceServiceMock->method('generateInvoiceData')->willReturn([
            'invoice' => $invoice,
            'contract' => $mockContract,
        ]);

        $this->entityManagerMock->method('persist')->willReturn(null);
        $this->entityManagerMock->method('flush')->willReturn(null);

        $request = Request::create('/process-payment/1', 'POST', [], [], [], ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '127.0.0.1']);
        $response = $this->controller->processPayment($request, 1);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::class, $response);
        $this->assertEquals('/app_billing', $response->getTargetUrl());
    }

    public function testProcessPaymentInvoiceNotFound()
    {
        $this->invoiceRepositoryMock->method('findInvoiceData')->willReturn(null);

        $this->entityManagerMock->method('persist')->willReturn(null);
        $this->entityManagerMock->method('flush')->willReturn(null);

        $request = Request::create('/process-payment/1', 'POST');
        $response = $this->controller->processPayment($request, 1);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse::class, $response);
        $this->assertEquals(404, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString(
            json_encode(['error' => 'Invoice not found']),
            $response->getContent()
        );
    }
}

Configuration:
# config/services_test.yaml
when@test:
  services:
    _defaults:
      public: true

    App\Repository\InvoiceRepository:
      public: true
    App\Service\InvoiceService:
      public: true
    Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface:
      public: true
    Knp\Snappy\Pdf:
      public: true
    Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface:
      public: true




You may try the mock builder with the actual EntityManager class, not the interface:
$this->entityManagerMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

